# Fitting special data

Tags: approximation

I have the following [file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ibdpvfrqvd6ndxy/evolve10.dat/file) which contains data, regarding the time evolution of the composition of a star. We are only interested in the first (time) and fourth column (mass). Let's make the corresponding plot

```
data = Import["evolve10.dat", "Table"];
d0 = data[[All, {1, 4}]];
L0 = ListPlot[d0, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> All]
```

As we see, the time-evolution of the mass $m$ is very unique. My question is: Is there a way to fit the data and obtain an analytic formula $m=m(t)$ approximating the time-evolution of the mass?

[image]

Comment: If you would like to obtain an analytic formula for physical data, you should know the model beforehand, or at least have narrowed it down to several possibilities. You could fit a 2000-degree polynomial to the data, but the formula would be meaningless and have no predictive power.

Comment: An adjusting as $$t(m) = \rho_0(1-e^{\frac{m}{\tau_0}})+\phi(m-m_1)\rho_1(1-e^{\frac{m-m_1}{\tau_2}})$$ with $\phi$ the Heaviside function would be easier to do.